# A basic "mount" question

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, mount

Am quite a novice here so please excuse me if I am sounding too stupid.
I am working on Linux(Fedora). I have three partions namely: Log, Backup and File system. On boot the File system is mounted. Now, I need to mount the file systems on Backup and Log and access/write to them from within a C program which I have in File system.

How do i do that? First and foremost I mount Log and Backup using the GUI interface and have no idea on which folder it is getting mounted so i don't know the path to it. Will be gratefull for pointers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [mount(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mount) and [getmntent(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getmntent)